# Caching result of evaluation in the notebook?

Tags: programming

Sometimes I have a cell which takes a while to re-evaluate, but the result is quite small. It would be nice to have an easy way to "cache" some computations by embedding the result in the notebook, and automatically reusing that result on rerun.

IE, instead of

`result = expr`

I would do

`result = memoizedEvaluation[expr]`

Any suggestions to how to implement this?

This was motivated by the cell below, result is small, but it takes couple of minutes to evaluate.

```
graphNamesOrig = 
 Join @@ Table[GraphData[k], {k, 80, 200}];
graphSpectraOrig = 
 N[GraphData[#, "LaplacianSpectrum"]] & /@ graphNamesOrig;
```

Comment: Do you want it to persist across Mathematica sessions, through kernel restart etc?

Comment: Have you seen `Iconize` and `PersistentSymbol`?

Comment: Control+Shift+L?

Comment: There is also [`Once`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Once.html).

Comment: @Kuba yes, the issue is recomputing state lost on kernel restart (which I have to do several times a day)

Comment: Aha, `Once[expr,"Local"]` seems to be the thing for this usecase

Comment: @Jason B. Using `Once` seems very promising. However, from the documentation, I could not understand how to use the option `"Local"`. Namely, looking at the example `res = Once[Import["http://www.wolfram.com/spikey/img/spikey.png"], 
  "Local"]`, I could not catch how to retrieve `res` during the next session. Should I have given a path to a certain file instead of `"Local"`? Or is there a place forming automatically where `res` is kept? Then, where? Could you please kindly explain it?

Comment: I think the trick is that `Once` remembers where it stores the stuff itself, so you just reevaluate the `Once` expression and get the precalculated and stored result instead of recalculating. If you wonder what happens behind the scene, most probably some kind of hashing of the expression to evaluate is used to generate a unique filename for each expression and that is stored in the object store directory that has a default but can be reconfigured. As the documentation states you can have a look at the `Once`-expressions are stored on you computer with: `PersistentObjects["Hashes/Once/*"]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check how many [`PersistentObjects`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PersistentObjects.html) you have already

```
Length@PersistentObjects["Hashes/Once/*", "Local"]
```

Now you can do your slow calculation using [`Once`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Once.html), here I'm timing using [`EchoTiming`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EchoTiming.html), and the function is [`RandomReal`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomReal.html)   so very unlikely to repeat the value.

```
EchoTiming[
    key = Once[
        CompoundExpression[
            Pause[1],
            Hash[RandomReal[9, 10^7]]
        ]
        , "Local"
    ]
]
```

Now you can see that you have more [`PersistentObjects`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PersistentObjects.html)

```
Length@PersistentObjects["Hashes/Once/*", "Local"]
```

You can now exit the Kernel

```
Exit[]
```

And repeat all the previous actions.

You should observe that subsequent evaluations take much shorter time, and always return the same value, as in the GIF below.

[image]